# How do I transform a grayscale image to RGB in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, tensor

I have a CNN model trained on this input shape

```
TensorShape([1, 128, 256, 3])
```

And after processing my image using skimage  I have the follwing shape

```
TensorShape([1, 128,256, 1])
```

What should I do in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this solution :

```
tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(
    images, name=None
)
```